# Error executing: DDE connection

Tags: visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have installed several versions of SQL Server on my machine, but visual source safe insists in opening any .sql file using Sql Server 2008 management studio.

I have changed the default application for files .sql to be opened using SQL Server 2014 management studio but now when I right click any of my scripts, either to view of edit, it comes out with the message "Error executing: DDE connection" as you can see on the picture below.

has anyone got any solution or suggesting for this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc0c9ac9-e8ba-41a5-9f7e-7486f7d8ea32/vss-no-longer-finds-the-registered-application-for-sql-files?forum=vssourcecontrol

> Have you tried setting this extention in VSS
>   Explorer->Tools->Options->Custom Editor?

or

> Could you try the following?
>
> 1. Rename
>
> ft000002 and ft000003 (whichever one you have listed under
>   OpenWithProgids) keys under HKCR
>
> and
>
> HKML->Software->Classes
>
> 1. Rename .sql record from
>
> HKCU->Software->Microsoft->Windows->CurrentVersion->Explorer->FileExt
>
> and from
>
> HKCR
>
> 1. Add just one association for .sql file using Windows explorer.
> 2. Check HKCU->Software->Microsoft->Windows->CurrentVersion->Explorer->FileExt->
>      OpenWithProgids   You should not have ft0000xx files in there now.
> 3. Check if VSS is working as expected now if not revert the changes.

Comment: I just went to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
on the .sql there was this value:ssms.sql.11.0
and I changed that value to this:ssms.sql.12.0
an on VSS I started to use the  "Registered Application" to view or edit files and I gladly noticed it was working all fine -> opening the files with SSMS sql server 2014, and if the ssms is already on, it just adds another tab to it with the new file. thanks BobNoobGuy